# String.Format()'s alignment behaves different when it comes to MessageBox

Tags: c#, messagebox, string.format

I am using String.Format() to format some text information and it works perfectly with "Console.WriteLine()" as documented in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

My code is like this:

```
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.AppendLine("Summary Information:");
        strBuilder.AppendFormat("{0,-10}{1,-8}{2,-10}{3,-30}{4,-7}\n", "Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4", "Header5");
        strBuilder.AppendFormat("{0,-10}{1,-8}{2,-10}{3,-30}{4,-7}\n\n", "A", "1", "Y", "Long Information", "13");
        string result = strBuilder.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The console result is shown below.

[image: Console Result]

But, when I try to show it on a MessageBox, the columns are shifting. Somehow the spaces are swallowed.

```
 MessageBox.Show(result, "MBox Test");
```

[image: MessageBox result]

It is also okay, because I wasn't very kneen on the "MessageBox" class of the .Net. It has so much limitations.

So I decided to implement a custom form to display this message. I have tried with Label and RichTextBox. But unfortunately the result was exactly same as the MessageBox.

And I am confused. Why .Net's own controls can not support String.Format()'s alignment. Is there any way I can handle this situation?

Comment: well after learning this is because of the font type, I've made a messagebox which works with html. so problem solved. and now I have much more flexibility formatting the messagebox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String.Format(...)` works perfectly well, but it does not align as a table in your message box because of the font!

In your console you use a fixed-width (monospace) font, but the messagebox uses one with dynamic width. Therefore e.g. an "M" consumes more space than an "i" or a " " (space) and this messes up your layout.

As [you can't change the messagebox font](https://stackoverflow.com/q/232066/4464570), you have to create your own frame with any kind of text widget that supports custom fonts, e.g a `TextBox` or just an ordinary `Label`.

Answer (score 4):

The console uses a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), whereas the message box uses a variable-width font. This is why it appears that the alignment is not kept in the message box.

In the console, a space is the same width as any other character. In the message box, a space is not as wide (and neither are characters like "i" and "l"), so things do not line up how you want them to.

The closest you'll be able to get to keeping the alignment in the message box is to use tabs instead of spaces, but even then things may not line up because of the length of some of the words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabs (\t) instead of spaces to get same distances between columns, it should work perfectly in every font-type :)

Answer (score 0):

In a pinch, using tabs after each column might work but is very hit and miss.

```
//I'm using Tuple Types and Interpolated Strings which are available in C# 7 and .NET 4.7+
(int, int, int) maxFieldLengths = (10, 10, 10); //Use 10 as the min length
List<(string, string, string)> values = new List<(string, string, string)>();
values.Add(("header1", "header2", "header3"));
values.Add(("value1", "value2", "value3"));
values.Add(("longerstringvalue", "value4", "evenlongerstringvaluehere"));

foreach (var value in values)
{
    maxFieldLengths.Item1 = Math.Max(maxFieldLengths.Item1, value.Item1.Length);
    maxFieldLengths.Item2 = Math.Max(maxFieldLengths.Item2, value.Item2.Length);
    maxFieldLengths.Item3 = Math.Max(maxFieldLengths.Item3, value.Item3.Length);
}

var messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var value in values)
{
    messageBuilder.AppendFormat($"{{0,{maxFieldLengths.Item1 * -1}}}\t| {{1,{maxFieldLengths.Item2 * -1}}}\t| {{2,{maxFieldLengths.Item3 * -1}}}{Environment.NewLine}",
        value.Item1, value.Item2, value.Item3);
}
MessageBox.Show(messageBuilder.ToString());
```

This produces:

[image: messagebox]

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this some time, and this is how I solved this:

```
string messageBoxText = "";

messageBoxText += "'Text 1'".PadRight(40) + "\t" + "text2" + "\n";
messageBoxText += "'Long Text 3'".PadRight(40) +"\t" + "text4" + "\n";

MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText);
```

You will get this formatted string inside your MessageBox, key is in adding `\t` after right padded text.

[image]